# How to stream video/audio to web browser

Tags: audio, video

I want to stream Video and audio from my webcam in Linux to the internet and play the streaming over the internet by using the normal web browser such as IE, firefox chrome..etc.

I am using now the mjpg-streamer, its work great but unfortunately it stream only video no audio.

What is the best way?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Video streaming as a standard module in HTML is relatively new, and so you have the choice whether to use the standard technology - which is, still, new and not widely-enough supported, or otherwise use the de-facto standard that is in the process of being replaced, but is fully supported in current browsers.

If you choose to go for the avant-garde HTML5-supported standard, the solutions for live-video are a bit complicated. The most common streaming solution would be using HTTP Live Streaming, which for a live stream requires a specialized streaming server (such as Darwin, FMS or Wowza) rather than an HTTP server. There are many choices to be made; I would go with H.264 encoding over MP4 file format served in the HTTP live streaming protocol. As for which streaming server to choose, I can't make a recommendation there as I only have experience with Wowza, but I can tell you that Wowza is usually a good choice as it's very flexible and easy to work with.

If you choose to go for the commonly supported de-facto standard, that would be using a Flash-based video player, such as JWPlayer from longtailvideo.com. To create a live feed for that, you can either use a streaming server (such as Wowza or FMS, which might be a good investment for the future if you choose to switch to HTML5 at some point) or if your video is accessed by one client at a time, you can configure a CGI script to be run by your HTTP server, and have it create a file in the FLV file format.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I will read about the JWPlayer and Wowza.